# The Get-VM is not recognized as a command after taking a session

Tags: powershell

> The term 'Get-VM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-VM:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

[image]

The PowerShell does not take the command Get-VM after taking session of VM.

Answer (score 1):

Get-VM is from a module that is not loaded by default (Hyper-V or VMM(?)).

You need to import the module first by using Import-Module, like for example:

Import-Module Hyper-V

This require that you have the windows feature where the module is found installed

Answer (score 0):

As you enter PS session on a different computer, the Get-VM command should be known to that computer. Can you try if Get-VM works on the target computer?